# Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am trying to add distance from user to the Location object, but this requires using an asynchronous call that I can't figure out where and how to do exactly. From there I will sort Locations by distance from user. I tried the code below bc it's where the sorted locations would be used, but I get an error saying "await" can only be used in "async" or "async*" methods even though it is being used with an async function. How do I add distance from user to a Location object given it requires an asynchronous call?

```
class MapWidget extends StatefulWidget {

...

@override
    _MapWidgetState createState() => _MapWidgetState();
}

class _MapWidgetState extends 
    State<MapWidget> {

    Future <List<Location>> sortLocations() async {
         return null;//function not done
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  final List<Location> sortedLocations = await sortLocations();
...
```

Comment: await can only be used with the async keyword for example : onPressed:() async{await .. //Your code here} . you can't asing a await keywoard to the statefulWidget, you will have to remove the await keywoard or asign a function then retrive the required output.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `await` functions in `build` method because it cannot be `async`.To use async operations in `build` you must use `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`.

```dart
Future<List<Location>> sortLocations() {
  ...
  return <Location>[];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Location>>(
    future: sortLocations(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
      }
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      }
      return ListView(...);
    },
  );
}
```

```dart
Future<List<Location>> sortLocations() {
  ...
  return <Location>[];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<List<Location>>(
    stream: sortLocations().asStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
      }
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      }
      return ListView(...);
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter there is a widget call FutureBuilder, that helps you build UI after the data is returned from an async function. You can use it as:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder<List<Location>>(
              future: sortLocations(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                var sortedLocations = snapshot.data;
                // Build your UI here
                return ...
              }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use await in build method instead use it in initState

```
final List<Location> sortedLocations= new List();

@override
void initState(){
super.initState();
getdata();

}

getdata()async{
 sortedLocations.clear();
 sortedLocations = await sortLocations();
 setState((){});

}
```

Comment: `initState` cannot be `async` also so this will not work.

Comment: Then use a method outside build with async and call that method in initstate , Easy as that

Comment: @BambinoUA ive edited this post check it out

Comment: This **will not work** because `async` operation takes some time to complete. Assume that `getdata` takes 5 seconds. So `build` will be executed already but `getdata` still did not return the result. That is why `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` must be used because they provide waiting status handling. I.e. when data is not ready `CIrcullarProgressIndicator` will be shown (`snapshot.hasData is false`) and only when data is ready (`snapshot.hasData is true` then widget will be redrawn.
So yours approach is no go.

Comment: set state makes the magic , this approach will work , I've edited check it

Comment: This approach **is incorrect**! `build` will be executed at once. Assume you use `ListView` which requires data for `children`. As your `getdata` still did not return result (do you remember delay of 5 seconds?) so you have `null` data and you will get a crash.
P.S. Just implement your answer and you will see.

Comment: you should check empty list or null list to display no data every time, that is the best practice, this approach is right

Comment: It looks like you didn't understand async operations and lifecycle of widget. Just implement `Scaffold` with `AppBar`, `actions`, `ListView` and try to "check empty list or null list". Interesting *where* will you do this check? :))
P.S> If you want use **wrong approaches** use it.